# Can someone help me to find out where is my Syntax Error? Unexpected token Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, rest

Rest server returns String. I am trying to get authorized in REST and comeback to angular. But I stuck here, and cant find my syntax error. Thank you very much!

```
        app.controller('lController', function($scope, $http)
        {
           $scope.login = function()
           {
            console.log("Login in");
        var endPoint = "http://localhost:8080/RestServer/main/just/Authorize";
        var jsonData = {
            username: $scope.username,
            password: $scope.password
        };
        var jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonData);

        $http.post(endPoint, jsonString,{headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}}).success(function (data,status, headers ){
            var d = JSON.parse(data);
            if(d.access == "ok")
            {
                Console.log(d);
                sh = d.id;
            }

        });

    }
});
```

Comment: may be the json returned is not valid..Check the json here - http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: please provide more details. can you upload console data.

Comment: Thank you! I have checked jsonlint.com, and my json seems correct, but still cant get trough this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure where your syntax error is but for starters, you don't need all that casting around of JSON.
Try this

```
   app.controller('lController', function($scope, $http) {
       $scope.login = function() {
           console.log("Login in");
           var endPoint = "http://localhost:8080/RestServer/main/just/Authorize";
           var userData = {
               username: $scope.username,
               password: $scope.password
           };

           $http.post(endPoint, userData).success(function(data, status, headers) {
               if (data.access && data.access == "ok") { //<-- checking for property existince like this is probably not the way to go, but it'll do here
                   Console.log(d);
                   sh = d.id;
               }

           });
       }
    });
```

*Note: Make sure your server returns content as `application/json`*

Comment: Thank you! My server actually returns String. JSON converted to string.

Comment: Yeah, so that is just normal JSON. Make sure your server returns the `Content-Type: application/json' header. Then Angular knows it needs to convert the response to a json object.

Comment: Thank you very much! It was a problem, I just add @Produces(MediaType.APPLICAION_JSON) on server side, and it works :) I am very beginner, thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 0):

1. `Console` written in Capital letter instead of `console`.
2. Variable `sh` is defined?